# How is creating Firebase audience based on events with parameters?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

If I created an audience based on events on Firebase with parameters, it will be the sum the parameters in audiences?

For example,

1. we have event "A" with parameter "value". Value is sending as integer and receiving in Firebase as a number.
2. User made 2 action sending us 2 times event "A":
3. the first time he send us event "A" with value:     "4" and
4. the second time he sends us event "A" with value "10".

If we have an audience named "X" with rule only users who events "A" and "value" is less than 5, a user from example above will disappear from that audience X after he sends us second event "A" because 10+4>5? Or he will stay on the audience "X" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audience membership is permanent.  Once the user has logged the event with A=4, the user will be a member of that audience, and no further event  will remove them from the audience.

Comment: This answer is obsolete, now you can specify membership duration etc. Check [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/01/a-crash-course-in-using-new-audiences.html)